# Selected HTML DIV element draggable using JQueryUi draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've an array of `jQuery` objects which are `draggable`.
What I want is when any element present in the array is dragged, All other elements should also be dragged.

Following is sample code that I have tried but I haven't got any success

```
$(event.target).parents('.ui-class-name').draggable({
   disabled : false,  
   helper: function() {
     var allSelectedEle = $($selected).map( function() {
         return this.toArray() 
     });
     return allSelectedEle;
}
});
```

Here `$selected` is the array of `jQuery` object

**Update:** Here is the [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uhX7h/1/) markup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save initial coordinates of elements, and update them while you dragging them ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uhX7h/2/)):

```
var els = $('.eq-ui-widget')
var coords = { x: 0, y: 0 }

function getSelected() {
    return els.filter('.selected')
}

els
.draggable({
    disbled: true,
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        getSelected().each(function() {
            var orig = $(this).data().orig
            $(this).css({
                top: orig.top + (ui.position.top - coords.y) ,
                left: orig.left + (ui.position.left - coords.x)
            })
        });
    },
    start: function(e, ui) {
        coords.x = ui.position.left;
        coords.y = ui.position.top;

        getSelected().each(function() {
            $(this).data().orig = $(this).position();
        });
    }
})
.on('click', function(event) {
    if(!event.ctrlKey) return;
    $(event.target).toggleClass('selected');
    /*logic for dragging  all selected elements simultaneously*/

    var selected = getSelected()
    els.draggable('option', 'disabled', true )
    selected.draggable('option', 'disabled', false )
});
```

Comment: I need to drag the selected elements and place them to the new place not to their clones

Comment: My draggable area and droppable container are same. I just want to move all elements to new position but all at once.